# PyDev + gurobipy + Fedora 18 = ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7, mathematical-optimization, importerror, gurobi

I am trying to use Gurobi's python module gurobipy on a Fedora 18 installation.

So far, I got the extracted and unmodified version of the Gurobi download to "work" by executing the Python binary distributed with Gurobi.

However, I cannot get it to include the gurobipy module:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gurobipy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from gurobipy import *
ImportError: libgurobi55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Since this is the distribution's Python2.7 version, I am not sure how to proceed, let alone integrate the library into my system's Python2.7 64 Bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyDev is finding the gurobi python libraries.  The gurobipy python library is not able to find the native shared libraries.  You need to add the location of libgurobi55.so to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH [environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had tried to do this before, but then failed because it was only set for the current shell. Now it is up and kicking. How blind I at times must seem.